# How add slide up/down effect to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, razor

I'm using `asp.net mvc5` with `razor engine` .I want to add `slide up` and `slide down` effects to a div . I spend many hours today to do it but I couldn't. I used a lots of jquery codes but they didn't work . I don't know why Jquery didn't work in my project . I'm very confused . please help me how can I add `slide up` `slide down` effects to this code? here's my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('btnShow');
    button.onmouseover = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('MyFooter');
    div.style.display = 'block';
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('btnHide');
    button.onmouseover = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('MyFooter');
    div.style.display = 'none';
          };
</script>
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you can do it like following. This code snippet may help you.

```js
$('#btnShow').mouseover(function() {
    $('#MyFooter').slideDown();
});
        
$('#btnHide').mouseover(function () {
    $('#MyFooter').slideUp();
});
```

```css
#MyFooter {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show"/>
<input type="button" id="btnHide" value="Hide"/>
<br/><br/>
<div id="MyFooter"></div>
```

**Update:** You have too many `script` tag. Your `script` section should like following. This may solve your problem.

```
@section scripts{
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("footer").hide();

           $('#btnShow').mouseover(function () {
               $('#MyFooter').slideDown();
           });

           $('#btnHide').mouseover(function () {
               $('#MyFooter').slideUp();
           });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but it didn't work , like many codes  I try today :(

Comment: This must work if you add `jquery` library correctly.

Comment: wooow , a big thank you . `slide up` works fine. but `slide down` didn't work . by the way very very thank you

Comment: If `slideUp` works then `slideDown` should work. You may misspelled `jQuery` selector.

Comment: I write codes exactly like you said . I don't know why one of them didn't work :/

Comment: Check your show button carefully. I think the problem is there. Check the `id` of that.

Comment: I'm sure every things is okay , every general things didn't work in my project ! I do all correctly

Comment: Are your buttons dynamically generated?

Comment: No , I used this tag `<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" id='btnShow'></button>`

Comment: It works fine now , Thank you dear . I never think too many script could be the problem . Thank you :)